# compare data in a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a scenario in which I have to check whether a data already exist in a table or not. If a user n application already exists then we don't need to perform any operation else perform insertion.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GroupName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicationName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserDeleted` BIT DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)

CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GroupName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicationName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

table1 is the main table while temp_table from which I have to perform comparision.

Sample date script:

```
INSERT  INTO `table1`(`ID`,`GroupName`,`UserName`,`ApplicationName`,`userdeleted`) 
VALUES 
('MidasSQLUsers','Kevin Nikkhoo','MySql Application',0),
('MidasSQLUsers','adtest','MySql Application',0),
('Salesforce','Kevin Nikkhoo','Salesforce',0),
('Salesforce','devendra talmale','Salesforce',0);

INSERT  INTO `temp_table`(`ID`,`GroupName`,`UserName`,`ApplicationName`,`userdeleted`) 
VALUES 
('MidasSQLUsers','Kevin Nikkhoo','MySql Application',0),
('MidasSQLUsers','adtest','MySql Application',0),
('Salesforce','Kevin Nikkhoo','Salesforce',0),
('Salesforce','Kapil Singh','Salesforce',0);
```

Also if a row of temp_table does not exist int table1 then its status should be as userdeleted 1 as i mentioned in desired output.

Result: table1

```
ID  GroupName   UserName    ApplicationName Deleted
1   MidasSQLUsers   Kevin Nikkhoo   MySql Application 0
2   MidasSQLUsers   adtest  MySql   ApplicationName   0
3   Salesforce  Kevin Nikkhoo   Salesforce    0
4   Salesforce  devendra talmale Salesforce   1
5   SalesForce  Kapil Singh Salesforce    0
```

Please help

Comment: You mean when `UserName` and `ApplicationName` exists, don't do insert? If so you can make `uniq(UserName, ApplicationName)` index on those fields and use `INSERT IGNORE ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick, change whatever is inside the concat, to met your specification.

first do one update to "delete" the rows that are not in tempTable:

```
   update table t1 set deleted = 'YES' 
    where concat( t1.groupName, t1.Username, t1.application) NOT IN 
    (select  concat( t2.groupName, t2.Username, t2.application) from tempTable t2);
```

second: insert the new records

```
insert into table1 t1 (t1.groupName, t1.username, t1.application_name, t1.deleted)

(select t2.groupName, t2.Username, t2.application, t2.deleted from tempTable t2    
where concat(t2.userName, t2.application, t2.groupName, t2.deleted) **not in** 
    (select concat(t3.userName, t3.application, t3.groupName, t3.deleted) 
       from table1 t3)
```

the [concat function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will make a new row from existing rows... this way I can compare multiple fields at same time as if I was comparing only one...

the ["not in"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) lets make you a query inside a query...

Comment: can you explain your code what this concat do and what I do with these **not in**

Comment: But from this query I will not resultant ouput that I required as if a row of temp_table is not exists in table1 then userdeleted column should be updated to 1

Comment: @KapilSingh am I expect to understand that from the example? the only thing you specified is that if a row does not exist is to be inserted, and that is what my query does.

Comment: oopes I apologize for that i missed that part.... plz give me query for this case also...

Comment: your query for insrtion is not working: it giving error Query : insert into dpuserapplication t1 (t1.groupName, t1.username, t1.applicationname, t1.deleted) (select t2.groupName, t2.Username, ...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1 (t1.groupName, t1.username, t1.applicationname, t1.deleted)

Comment: INSERT INTO dpuserapplication t1 (t1.groupName, t1.username, t1.applicationname, t1.deleted)

(SELECT t2.groupName, t2.Username, t2.applicationname FROM temp_userapplication t2    
WHERE CONCAT(t2.userName, t2.applicationname, t2.groupName) NOT IN 
    (SELECT CONCAT(t3.userName, t3.applicationname, t3.groupName) 
       FROM dpuserapplication t3)

Comment: my query looks fine, try replace  **not in** by NOT IN... and make sure all the names of the fields are correctly written

Comment: @KapilSingh - you have a missing close bracket (to match the open bracket before the first select).

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on the above queries.

Using JOINs, which if you have an index on the userName, application and groupName fields will likely be faster

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_table t2
ON t1.userName = t2.userName
AND t1.application = t2.application
AND t1.groupName = t2.groupName
SET t1.deleted = CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

For the normal insert

```
INSERT INTO table1 t1 (t1.groupName, t1.username, t1.application_name, t1.deleted)
(SELECT t2.groupName, t2.Username, t2.application, t2.deleted 
FROM tempTable t2    
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t3
ON t2.userName = t3.userName
AND t2.application = t3.application
AND t2.groupName = t3.groupName
WHERE t3.ID IS NULL)
```

Comment: one more problem i faced... if a rows whose status t1.deleted = 1 and later if i get an entry for same values in temp_table then it wont get inserted into table1 as it should be.. what to do for this or its t1.deleted should reset to 0 again

Comment: Could that be sorted with the UPDATE statement as I have amended it above?